# Update QuerySet by attribute variable

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Take for example my data below where `prop` is the queryset I am trying to update, and `results` is a dict of information. This dict has keys that are attributes in this queryset, and also has keys that are not attributes in this QuerySet . I only want to update this QuerySet if it's attribute matches...

```
prop = Property.objects.get(pk=14)
results = {'price': '525000', 'code': '55285', 'estimate': '1500'}
```

I know this does not work as it calls for an attribute literally named 'apicall' but this is the logic that I am looking to achieve:

```
for apicall in results:
 if hasattr(prop,apicall):
  prop.apicall = results[apicall]
  prop.save()
```

How can I avoid calling literally `prop.apicall` and instead `prop.price` if it exists in the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`setattr(…)`** builtin function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr), and thus use:

```
for apicall in results:
    if hasattr(prop,apicall):
        setattr(prop, apicall, results[apicall])
prop.save()
```

It is likely better to save `prop` *after* all the changes, otherwise we will perform a lot of extra database queries.

Comment: I guess I should have continued to RTFM. Also setattr requires 3 arguments, where the new value should be input. Thanks so much!

Comment: @BlakeRussell: aaarrgggghhh... thanks, that was indeed a mistake :(